# T4 a namespace cannot directly contain membes such as fields or methods

Tags: c#, t4

Hi I am just starting out with T4 templates and I need to generate a javascript file based on the actions in my controller.

I got the code all figured out forgetting the controllers and actions my only problem is that I am getting this error in the T4 template file and I do not understand it:

> Compiling transformation: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

This is my code:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetPath)" #>

<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="eConnect.WebApi.Helpers.T4.ControllerDetails" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Web.Http;"#>
<#@ output extension=".js" #>

define(['services/logger', 
        'services/jsonDataService', 
        'services/config', 
        'services/cachingService'],
        function (logger, jsonDataService, config, cache) {
            var dataService = { };
            return dataService;
        });

<#
    var controllers = ControllersInfo.GetControllers();
    foreach(var controller in controllers) {
        Dictionary<string, ParameterInfo[]> actions = ControllersInfo.GetAllCustomActionsInController(controller, new HttpGetAttribute());
    }
#>
```

There is also an external class that gets the controllers and actions but I do not think it's necesary for the current problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably have this figured out by now but:

```
<#@ import namespace="System.Web.Http;"#>
```

Note the ';'

Instead write:

```
<#@ import namespace="System.Web.Http"#>
```